# 1 if the value is NOT NULL otherwise NULL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a new table and carrying over one of the fields from a previous table. I need to set the value to 1 if value is not null otherwise leave it as NULL.

Is this possible to do without an update statement? I understand that in MSSQL you can use ISNULL function, but how about Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` would do that. For example:

```
create table new_table as
  select case when that_column is null then null else 1 end as that_column,
         other_column
  from the_original_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle offers the `nvl2()` function:

```
nvl2(col, 1, null)
```

If you want to change the value, though, you need to use an `update` or modify the data *somehow*.

Comment: The column is a date column in a previous table and is prepopulated with data. All I want to do is carry it over to the new table and set values to 1 where date is present otherwise set to NULL.

Comment: @Matetov_718 . . . You can include this expression rather than the column name.